# Dropdown menu inside Bootstrap panel group not completely visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a dropdown menu to work with a collapsible panel group.  The dropdown works fine if I take it out of the `.panel-group` div.  I am using Bootstrap 3.0.3

Non-working js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/E2rqA/

and this is how it should look:
http://jsfiddle.net/ShCaf/

Comment: Anything in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473769/bootstrap-drop-down-cutting-off) help?

Comment: Were you trying to replicate the example exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because of the following rule applied from bootstrap.css.

```
.panel-group .panel {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   overflow: hidden; /*This is the issue*/
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

You can override the overflow for your own panel. You can add the following rule to make it more specific to your panel.

```
#sessionaccordion.panel-group .panel {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwaG5/)**

Comment: This is how you answer a so question.